# Line plot displaying sequence of events by age using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, line-plot

Consider the `df` below in which there are different `sequences` of `events` and the individuals age when they occur (`A:E`). If an `event` does not occur, the correspondent `column` receives `NA`. The `sequence` `proportion` is given in the `column` `prop`.

```
df <- data.frame(seq_id = seq(1,5),
                 seq = as.character(c("A>B>D", "A>B", "A>D>B", "A>C>E", "A>B>E")),
                 prop = sample(seq(5,50), 5, replace=T),
                 A = c(41,38,60,45,47),
                 B = c(42,40,68,NA,52),
                 C = c(NA,NA,NA,50,NA),
                 D = c(45,NA,62,NA,NA),
                 E = c(NA,NA,NA,78,80)
                 )

df
  seq_id   seq prop  A  B  C  D  E
1      1 A>B>D   13 41 42 NA 45 NA
2      2   A>B    8 38 40 NA NA NA
3      3 A>D>B   35 60 68 NA 62 NA
4      4 A>C>E    5 45 NA 50 NA 78
5      5 A>B>E   37 47 52 NA NA 80
```

I want to obtain a `plot` similar to the one below (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jbi.2018.11.002), where only the `events` that occur is displayed in each trajectory `line`:

[image]

I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result the first step is to reshape to long, then you can create your chart using a `geom_point` and a `geom_path`. The rest is to add the labels and adding more or less styling or sugar.

Note: Instead of the sequence id I opted to put the sequence on the  y axis.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df |>
  pivot_longer(-c(1:3), names_to = "event") |>
  filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
  arrange(seq_id, value) |> 
  mutate(seq = fct_inorder(seq))

df_long |>
  ggplot(aes(value, seq, color = event)) +
  geom_path(
    aes(group = seq),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(5, "pt"))
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label = event),
    vjust = 1, fill = NA, label.size = 0,
    label.padding = unit(8, "pt"),
    color = "black"
  ) +
  geom_label(aes(label = value),
    vjust = 0, fill = NA, label.size = 0,
    label.padding = unit(8, "pt"),
    color = "black"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = df,
    aes(label = scales::percent(prop, scale = 1)),
    x = 90,
    color = "black"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.05, 0, 0.05, 10)) +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 6) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Age",
    y = "Sequence"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: That is the output I needed, thank you.